# Quarkus Panache MongoDB: Serialize ObjectId as String

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm following the tutorials https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache and https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache to implement a simple MongoDB entity and resource with Quarkus Panache MongoDB.

Here's what I have so far:

```kotlin
@MongoEntity(collection = "guests")
class GuestEntity(
    var id: ObjectId? = null,
    var name: String? = null
)

@ApplicationScoped
class GuestRepository: PanacheMongoRepository<GuestEntity>

interface GuestResource: PanacheMongoRepositoryResource<GuestRepository, GuestEntity, ObjectId>
```

When running this, I can create a document by calling

```
POST localhost:8080/guest
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Foo"
}
```

The response contains the created entity

```json
{
  "id": {
    "timestamp": 1618306409,
    "date": 1618306409000
  },
  "name": "Foo"
}
```

Notice, how the `id` field is an object whereas I would like it to be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the application was using `quarkus-resteasy` instead of `quarkus-resteasy-jackson`.

Once the proper dependency was in place, everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

To serialize the `id` field as a String, apply the following annotation to the `id` **field**:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize
import io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.jackson.ObjectIdSerializer

@MongoEntity(collection = "guests")
class GuestEntity(
    // important: apply the annotation to the field
    @field:JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer::class)
    var id: ObjectId? = null,
    var name: String
)
```

Now the response is

```json
{
  "id": "607567590ced4472ce95be23",
  "name": "Foo"
}
```

Comment: While the answer is correct we register the serializer from the MongoDB with Panache extension so it should works.
This is an issue Kotlin as it works for Java. Can you open an issue describing the issue with MongoDB with Panache, Kotlin and the ObjectIdSerializer not applied ?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16470

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it in my TODO list if nobody else pick it before ...